# Visual studio 2017 split pane window

Tags: android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am currently working on an Android project. I need help splitting my Visual Studio 2017 working window into preview and code. I have searched the VS online documentation, tried their methods and also googled the problem.

Basically I want it so that I can see the android preview on the right side and the code window on the left side.

It allows you to split the window in code view, but when you change the one split window to designer the split disappears and the whole window becomes the design view.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a second window from the main menu **Window** - **New Window**.